# Access DOM when using hyper.Component

Tags: javascript, hyperhtml

When using [`HyperHTMLElement`](https://github.com/WebReflection/hyperHTML-Element) it's possible to access the contents of the component by simply using `this.children` or `this.querySelector()`, since it's an element.

But how would I achieve similar behavior when using [`hyper.Component`](https://viperhtml.js.org/hyperhtml/documentation/#components-3)?

The hypothetical example I have in mind is from React docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html - I'd like to focus a specific node inside my DOM.

I have a codepen sandbox where I'm trying to solve this: https://codepen.io/asapach/pen/oGvdBd?editors=0010

The idea is that `render()` returns the same `Node` every time, so I could save it before returning and access it later as `this.node`:

```
render() {
  this.node = this.html`
    <div>
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="button" value="Focus the text input" onclick=${this} />
    </div>
  `;
  return this.node;
}
```

But that doesn't look clean to me. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `handleEvent` pattern is there to help you. The idea behind that pattern is that you never need to retain DOM references when the behavior is event-driven, 'cause you can always retrieve nodes via `event.currentTarget`, always pointing at the element that had the listener attached, or `event.target`, suitable for clicks happened in other places too within a generic click handler attached to the wrap element, in your demo case the `div` one.

If you'd like to use these information, you can enrich your components using an attribute to recognize them, like a `data-is="custom-text-input"` on the root element could be, and reach it to do any other thing you need.

```
onclick(e) {
  var node = e.target.closest('[data-is=custom-text-input]');
  node.querySelector('[type=text]').focus();
}
```

You can see a working example in a fork of your code pen:
https://codepen.io/WebReflection/pen/RLNyjy?editors=0010

As alternative, you could render your component and address its content once as shown in this other fork:
https://codepen.io/WebReflection/pen/LzEmgO?editors=0010

```
  constructor() {
    super().node = this.render();  
  }
```

at the end of the day, if you are not using custom elements but just basic, good'ol DOM nodes, you can initialize / render them whenever you want, you don't need to wait for any upgrade mechanism.

What is both nice and hopefully secure here, is that there's no way, unless you explicitly expose it, to address/change/mutate the instance related to the DOM element.

I hope these possibilities answered your question.

Comment: I was thinking about using `event.target` as an option, too.

Comment: do you think calling `render()` in the constructor is really a good idea?

Comment: if you need to reference the root node, calling render sooner or later makes no difference. The cost of updating hyperHTML content twice with the same content is close to zero so even if later on the component will be re-rendered there won't be performance issues. However, for non critical components where you really need to directly access the root node, I'd prefer the event-driven way to work with the DOM. It's definitively more clean.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I've worked on in the past via https://github.com/joshgillies/hypercomponent

The implementation is actually quite trivial.

```
class ElementalComponent extends hyper.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    const _html = super.html
    this.html = (...args) => {
      this.node = _html.apply(this, args)
      return this.node
    }
  }
}

class HelloWorld extends ElementalComponent {
  render () {
    return this.html`<div>Hello World!</div>`
  }
}
```

This works really well and is inline with your question. However, it's worth noting `hyperHTML` can render not only a single node but also multiple nodes. As an example:

```
hyper`<div>Hello World!</div>` // returns a single DOM Node
hyper`<div>Hello</div> <div>World!</div>` // returns multiple DOM Nodes as an Array.
```

So `this.node` in the above `ElementalComponent` can be either a DOM Node, or Array based on what the renderer is doing.